# Catch block for exception thrown in a destructor

Tags: c++

I have some "nested" try catch blocks, split across functions, but essentially it boils down, for classes `Foo` and `Bar`, to this:

```
try {
    for (;;){
        try
        {
            Foo foo;
            try {
                Bar bar;
                if (something){
                    continue;
                }
            } catch (...){
                std::cout << "inner";
            }
        } catch (...){
            std::cout << "middle";
        }
    }
} catch (...){
    std::cout << "outer";
}
```

Both classes can throw exceptions in their destructors.

If `continue` is reached then as the stack unwinds, and during the destruction of `foo` and `bar`, an exception is thrown, then I'm expecting to print "outer", but it doesn't do that. What is going on?

Comment: why would it print something? where are you throwing an exception?

Comment: @DavidHaim as it says "Both classes can throw exceptions in their destructors".

Comment: you don't throw an exception from a destructor. see http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#ctor-exceptions

Comment: Unfortunately I use a 3rd party base class that does. So needed to know which catch site the exception will go to.

Comment: "If continue is reached then as the stack unwinds, and during the destruction of foo and bar, an exception is thrown" - this shows some confusion somewhere. The stack doesn't unwind _until_ an exception is thrown. "continue" being reached has nothing to do with stack unwinding.

Comment: then you should seriusly think if you want to use third party base class that causes undefined behaviour in such explicit and vulgar way

Comment: Oh I see. So the continue is not reached so the exception is thrown at a more nested site? Put as an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: @P45Imminent oh wait I understand what you were saying now. If continue is reached, then yes, the `foo` and `bar` objects go out of scope. But they are destroyed _before_ they go out of scope. The containing `try` ... `catch` block still applies. Bathsheba's answer is quite correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard makes this clear:

If a destructor throws an exception then it is caught by the `try` block in which the variable is **defined**.

So if `~Bar()` throws an exception, then the output is "inner". If `~Foo()` throws, then the output is "middle";